# Congratulations to Polynomial

Tags: discussion, reputation

Somehow @Polynomial managed to quietly get up to 120k without many folks noticing!

4th out of our 180,000 members, with nearly 1000 answers *and* 65 questions!

Congratulations!

Comment: It's the Question count that really gets me! 65 really useful questions!

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations on the milestone! Here are some great ones:

- [A 1k+ question, and maybe the most popular duplicate target on the site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)
- [I'm a robot in a warehouse full of boxes.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/98538) (I have used this method IRL, and it works great.)
- [Poor, poor Dave... `summon_cthulhu();`](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25588/98538)
- [Careful explanations of complex topics.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18557/98538)